# Wiki page import

Tags: wiki

I have a very long structured text file I want to import as hundreds of wiki pages.

I got OmniOutliner, which allows me to export my file as a number of useful formats like Excel, CSV, OPML, etc.

But I can't find a wiki engine that will import any of that.

Ideas?  I'm not concerned with what wiki engine or hosted service I have to use as long as it's not too hard to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've imported into Mediawiki, which uses an XML format.

I would set Mediawiki up, and then export a page so you can see what the basic XML structure is. Then write some scripts (or use search and replace) to generate an XML file for import. The basic structure is something like this

```
<mediawiki> <siteinfo> ... stuff
</siteinfo>
<page> ...stuff including title...
<text>
page text here
</text>
</page> </mediawiki>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:Importing_XML_dumps
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:XML_Import_file_manipulation_in_CSharp
- http://www.wikihow.com/Import-XML-Dumps-to-Your-MediaWiki-Wiki
- [Daniel Barrett’s "MediaWiki" on Import](http://books.google.com/books?id=2dhL5V3pLHkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=mediawiki&ei=mi8CSpz_DIfSNPCQkfID#v=onepage&q&f=false) (@ google-books)